# Dynamically create an .ics file and send as an e-mail attachment

Tags: php, forms, email, icalendar

So I have this form and the client is inquiring about sending an .ics file with the information from the form. This would be dynamically created every time and sent as an attachment in a dynamically created e-mail.

So my question is twofold. One, can you create an ICS file on the fly and two, can you send it as an attachment?

It's a PHP 5.x.x environment by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ICS files are just plaintext files, so it's trivial to generate one with PHP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Once you've generated it, you can trivially do mail attachments with [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) and [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org). Haven't used swiftmailer, but I do know PHPMailer has a function to create attachments from a variable, not a file.

Comment: Although I do need to have it generated on the fly as the registrant's name and other info will need to go into the .ics file which is why I was wondering if I can do it in PHP.

Comment: If your iCalendar file is very simple, contains no special characters, etc, creating it manually by concatenating a string may be good enough. If you need it to be more robust and correct for edge-cases it may be helpful to use a library to generate it. This is not unlike generating xml files.

Comment: For instance, if your description is coming from a users' input, you really don't want to just drop that in an iCalendar file unescaped. The rules for escaping can be a bit complex.