# import ics file to outlook automatically in php

Tags: php, icalendar

I am doing conference room booking project in joomla. (ie. *jevents*). after create a booking mail should go to team members with calendar appointment automatically.

For that i have used the code like below its generating ics file but i need to change this to automatic process. Experts can give idea or steps to finish this module.

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=alert.ics"); /* for ics file */

/*$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$time = $_POST['time'] . '00';
$summary = $_POST['summary'];*/

$year = '2012'; /* year */
$month = '11'; /* month */
$day = '30'; /* day */
$time = '12:00'; /* time of the events */
$summary = 'Treat in Chennai Five Star Hotel';

echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
echo "PRODID:-//YourSite//NONSGML YourSite//EN\n";
echo "METHOD:PUBLISH\n"; // required by Outlook
echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
echo "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-www.vrv.it\n"; // required by Outlook
echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n"; // required by Outlook
echo "DTSTART:$year"."$month"."$day"."T"."$time\n"; //20120824T093200 (Datetime format required) 
echo "SUMMARY:$summary\n"; /* summary */
echo "DESCRIPTION: this is just a test\n"; /* Description */
echo "END:VEVENT\n";
echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
?>
```

Comment: can anyone tell the idea....

Comment: what do you mean by automatic process?

Comment: now if i run this code means it can generate the ics file... then i need to import in outlook but i need to do this import process automatically...

Comment: After cerate a room for meeting the mail should go and also calendar should update...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create an .ics file and send as an e-mail attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984390/dynamically-create-an-ics-file-and-send-as-an-e-mail-attachment)

Comment: You need to add METHOD:REQUEST; ORGANIZER:TEST;ATTENDEE;CN="TEST";ROLE=ATTENDEE;RSVP:FALSE;MAILTO:me@yahoo.com